# Using winpcap library in qt creator

Tags: c++, c, qt5, pcap, winpcap

i need to use winpcap library in my c++11/qt5 project, and just after including library i'm getting errors like on the screenshot: [click](http://fotoo.pl/show.php?img=654636_pcap-errors.png.html).
In pro file i have

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -lwpcap
INCLUDEPATH += D:/Qt/Pr_inz1/WpdPack/Include
LIBS += -L D:/Qt/Pr_inz1/WpdPack/Lib -lwpcap -lpacket
```

I'm including this library like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <pcap.h>
    #include <winsock.h>
}
```

How can fix problems with

```
'u_int' does not name a type typedef u_int bpf_u_int32;
'bpf_u_int32' does not name a type bpf_u_int32 snaplen;
```

I tried add

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
```

but this nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to `#include <winsock2.h>`
before `#include <pcap.h>`